# Having multiple datepicker and linking them all together

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using this https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker as a datepicker. I have a problem on how to link the multiple datepickers making them all the same. One for the header and one for the main page. If i click the datepicker on the the header and change the date it should be the same in the main page same goes when i change the date on the main page header must change as well. Making them all linked together. It only initialize and works the one on the header. On reload the datepicker on the header shows the date today and the date for tomorrow. When you change the date for arrival the departure also change for the date for tomorrow. It works on the header but doesn't work on the mainpage, It does not show the date today and the date for tomorrow when reload but shows on the header. When you click the date for the arrival on the main page the date for the departure does not change it still gets the date on the header. Please help.

My code.

Header

```
   <input type="text" name="dateArrival" class="datepicker arrivalDate">
   <input type="text" name="dateDeparture"class="datepicker departureDate">
```

Mainpage

```
   <input type="text" name="dateArrival" class="datepicker arrivalDate">
   <input type="text" name="dateDeparture"class="datepicker departureDate">
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var nowDate = new Date();
    var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: today 
});

    $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $(".departureDate").datepicker("setDate", "+1d");
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});

    $(".arrivalDate").change(function() {
        addDay($(".arrivalDate").val(), '.departureDate');
    });


});

    function addDay(date_val,fld){
        var dt = new Date(date_val);
        var dt_new = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),(dt.getDate() + 1));
                $(fld).val((((dt_new.getMonth() + 1) <=9) ? "0"  + (dt_new.getMonth() + 1) : (dt_new.getMonth() + 1)) + "/" + (((dt_new.getDate()) <=9) ? "0" + dt_new.getDate() : dt_new.getDate()) + "/" + dt_new.getFullYear());
    }
```

Comment: When one date picker gets changed place the newly selected date into a variable. Then use `.datepicker("setDate", dateVar);` on the other date pickers to update their values.

Answer (score 0):

A working example, sorry I can't find out what is wrong with yours:

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
$("[name='dateDeparture']").change(function(){
    $("[name='dateDeparture']").val($(this).val());
});
$("[name='dateArrival']").change(function(){
    $("[name='dateArrival']").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<input type="text" placeholder="Arrival Date" name="dateArrival" class="datepicker arrivalDate">
<input type="text" placeholder="Departure Date" name="dateDeparture" class="datepicker departureDate">
<hr>
<input type="text" placeholder="Arrival Date" name="dateArrival" class="datepicker arrivalDate">
<input type="text" placeholder="Departure Date" name="dateDeparture" class="datepicker departureDate">
```

Comment: thanks they are now all link together but i still have the problem on the main page regarding that there's no date for today or tomorrow. It only shows on the header page. What i need is upon reload it automatically gets the date for today and tomorrow on the header and the main page. What i have now is only the header gets the date for today and tomorrow automatically or upon reload. thanks in advance.